# SQL Insert query in function

Tags: php, sql

I have this PHP function:

```
function InsertQuery($table, $cols, $values) {
    global $conn;
    $InsertQuery_Sql = "INSERT into $table (" . implode(",", $cols) . ") values (" . implode("','", $values) . "'') ";
    echo $InsertQuery_Sql;
    $InsertQuery_Rs = mysql_query($InsertQuery_Sql, $conn);
}
```

I am calling the function here:

```
$cols = array("ticketnumber", "status");
$values = array("1234", "Open");
InsertQuery('tickets', $cols, $values);
```

and the SQL looks like:

```
INSERT into tickets (ticketnumber,status) values (1234','Open'')
```

this is producing errors as there is an extra ' on the end, how can I stop this from happening?

Comment: you are adding `''` in your query builder. single `'` is enough.

Comment: you mean in the function?

Comment: yes. in your function only

Comment: Speaking of extra quotes, an apostrophe in any of the data is likely to cause problems.  Escaping those is only of the many benefits of query parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there must be a `'` before

```
$InsertQuery_Sql="INSERT into $table (".implode(",", $cols).") values ('".implode("','", $values)."') ";
```

Answer (score 3):

You are adding `''` yourself at the end of your query. Edit

```
$InsertQuery_Sql="INSERT into $table (".implode(",", $cols).") 
                  values (".implode("','", $values)."'') ";
                                                     ^^
                                                     your culprit
```

and replace trailing `''` with `'`:

```
$InsertQuery_Sql="INSERT into $table (".implode(",", $cols).") 
                  values (".implode("','", $values)."')";
```

**EDIT**

While this is answer to your question about `''`, in fact your code is bad in other areas too: you should not use `mysql` extension as it is deprecated -> use `mysqli` or even better `PDO`. You should **escape** any passed values prior using it (see `mysqli_real_escape_string()`, otherwise you are vulnerable to SQLInjection attack.

As for lack of opening `'` - just add it:

```
$InsertQuery_Sql="INSERT into $table (".implode(",", $cols).") 
                  values ('".implode("','", $values)."')";
```

Comment: i have changed my query, but it seems its also not adding a ' to the first value

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom function to implode and wrap the values:

```
function implode_wrapped($before, $after, $glue, $array) 
{
    $out = '';
    foreach ( $array as $item ){
        $out .= $before.$item.$after.$glue;
    }

    return substr($out, 0, -strlen($glue));
}

$InsertQuery_Sql="INSERT into $table (".implode_wrapped('`', '`', ',', $cols).") values (".implode_wrapped("'", "'", ',', $values).") ";
```

You should also stop using mysql_ functions and switch to mysqli_ or, more preferrably, PDO.

Answer (score 0):

Using the procedural style mysql_ commands is old and deprecated; you shouldn't be using them at all.

While @Marcin Orlowski does give an example of how to solve this; he isn't really addressing any other of the problems with your code. Even with his code, depending on where `$values` comes from, your ccode is completely open to MySQL injections.

I'd suggest rewriting your codebase to using MySQLi and prepared statements. See the [quick start guide](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php).

Answer (score 0):

// edit function like this..

```
function InsertQuery($table, $cols, $values) {
       global $conn;
       $InsertQuery_Sql = "INSERT into $table (" . implode(",", $cols) . ") values ('" .            implode("','", $values) . "') ";
       echo $InsertQuery_Sql;
       $InsertQuery_Rs = mysql_query($InsertQuery_Sql, $conn);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$InsertQuery_Sql = "INSERT into $table (" . implode(",", $cols) . ") values ('" . implode("','", $values) . "') ";
```

Comment: nice deal copying my post :)